# Deleting Windows DNS PTR entries with dnscmd

Tags: windows, dns

on a Windows DNS server, I can add a resource record and also create its corresponding PTR for the reverse lookup zone automatically by using the following powershell command

dnscmd . /recordadd mgmt.test rhel1 ***/CreatePTR*** A 10.0.0.1

Is there a way to delete both of them with a single command like above?

In short, is there a dnscmd switch that works as the opposite of ***/createPTR*** ?
Something like /removePTR or /deletePTR? Cant find any documentation that says so

Comment: Did you ever get an answer or solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure you supply the address you want removed from the reverse lookup zone:

```
dnscmd . /recorddelete mgmt.test rhel1 A 10.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

First you [have](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-uk/library/cc772390%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) [those](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-uk/library/cc772069%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) [pages](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772069%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_15).

I don't know what /CreatePTR does but it seems it doesn't exist in the latest windows server version.

Anyway, I don't think this should be different than deleting a normal record.

Sorry for just using hyperlinks.